# Android program crash on random error (caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android, memory-management, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, ddms

My program runs just fine and then I always encounter a random crash error (eg. Error inflating class ) which is almost always started by a OutOfMemoryError.

I watched my VM Heap in DDMS and it looks like gc is doing it's job as I'll watch the `%used` go up and down along with the `#Objects`

I've noticed that I get the crash when I have close to these stats:

```
Heap Size    11.820 MB
Allocated    7.020 MB
Free         4.801 MB
% Used       59.39%
# Objects    148,927
```

This is about the peak of usage on the device. Sometimes it crashes here, but other times it allows me to move around to another category which allows GC to do it's work getting the `%used` down to 32%. However, I usually crash shortly after even though usage is down.

I typically crash out with a chain of errors. The top-most `Caused by:` error is usually something like `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`

I'm not sure where to go next as the device seems fine on resources when it crashes, but complains about not having enough memory. I've tried running the program without images and I still get an app that crashes. Regardless, where should I start looking to find the *culprit*?

** EDIT **

Kindle Fire on Android 2.3.4 via Eclipse

Answer (score 2):

In pre-honeycomb android versions bitmap data stores outsize VM heap, so its impossible to track bitmap data via DDMS :)
There are two possible reasons: 
1. Your interface use giant count of images
2. You create bitmaps manually and memory leak occurs. In one Google IO presentation was said that several garbage collections necessary to completely free bitmap memory

---

Sorry, missed that app crashed without images. Try [dump](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#dumpHprofData%28java.lang.String%29) memory usage periodically and see it later via Eclipse Memory Analyzer

Comment: I added the OS version# in an edit which is definitely pre-honeycomb (good call). In my app I have two sections that are both ViewPagers. On "destroyItem" I'm not tossing the "pages" because they take a while to load (and I get the same error either way) so I'm leaving them present and just not re-instantiating. On one section I get somewhere around 120 thumbnails going (6 pages X ~20 thumbs a page). Changing sample size didn't help either, so I'm not convinced it's the images. Anyway, enough babbling from me. I'm going to give your memory dump idea a shot momentarily.